# Wt - Example of QueryModel and WTableView?

Tags: c++, wt

I'm beginning with Wt, and after taking the basics of ORM module, I'm trying to show the results of a table (TableTags) with no success.

I have defined table TableTag as:

```
class TableTag
{
public:
    static const unsigned int tableVersion = 1;
    std::string name;
    //Wt::Dbo::collection< Wt::Dbo::ptr<TablePost> > tablePosts;

    TableTag();
    ~TableTag();
    static void initTableRecords(Wt::Dbo::Session &_session);

    template<class Action>
    void persist(Action &_action)
    {
        Wt::Dbo::field(_action, name, "Name");

        //Wt::Dbo::hasMany(_action, tablePosts, Wt::Dbo::ManyToMany, "Post");
    }
};
typedef Wt::Dbo::collection< Wt::Dbo::ptr<TableTag> > TableTags;
```

and I'm begginning with a code similar to:

```
DDBBApp::setDDBBBackendAndSession(ddbbBackend_,ddbbSession_);
ddbbSession_.mapClass<TableTag>("TableTag");
{
    Wt::Dbo::Transaction transaction(ddbbSession_);

    Wt::Dbo::QueryModel<TableTag> * qmTags = new Wt::Dbo::QueryModel<TableTag>();
    TableTags tags = ddbbSession_.find<TableTag>();
    Wt::Dbo::Query<TableTag> qTag(ddbbSession_.find<TableTag>());
    qmTags->setQuery(qTag);


    WTableView * wtv = new WTableView();
    wtv->setModel(qmTags);
}
```

but compiler complains with this error (VS2013, translated to English):

> DDBBApp.cpp(54): error C2664:
>   'Wt::Dbo::Query::Query(Wt::Dbo::Session
>   &,const std::string &,const std::string &)' : argument 1 cannot be converted from 'Wt::Dbo::Query' to 'const
>   Wt::Dbo::Query &'

I've tried several constructors, variable types, etc... I know the point is close to this:

```
Wt::Dbo::QueryModel<TableTag> * qmTags = new Wt::Dbo::QueryModel<TableTag>();

Wt::Dbo::Query< Wt::Dbo::ptr<TableTag> > q1 = ddbbSession_.find<TableTag>();
qmTags->setQuery(qTag); //Error here

Wt::Dbo::Query<TableTag> q2 = ddbbSession_.find<TableTag>(); //Error here
qmTags->setQuery(q2);
```

But I'm not able to deal with this, I think the right way is 2nd one, according to the docu and snippets I've googled.

Can someone post a simple example so I can clarify how Wt works with this?

Wy the wall, I'm using Wt 3.3.3 under Win 8.1 + VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it ^_^ thanks to: [Not getting headers on WTableView with QueryModel](http://redmine.emweb.be/boards/1/topics/8050?r=8054#message-8054)

The rigth piece of code is as follows:

```
Wt::Dbo::QueryModel< Wt::Dbo::ptr<TableTag> > * qmTags1 = new Wt::Dbo::QueryModel< Wt::Dbo::ptr<TableTag> >();
qmTags1->setQuery(ddbbSession_.find<TableTag>());
qmTags1->addAllFieldsAsColumns();

WTableView * wtv1 = new WTableView();
wtv1->setModel(qmTags1);
this->root()->addWidget(wtv1);
```

Note: don't forget to use QueryModel->setQuery()!!